# How to sort list of objects by various object variables in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sorting, string-comparison

Having this object:

```
class Data (region: String, language: String, version: String)
```

with these instances:

```
var data1 = Data("Spain", "En, Pl", "")
var data2 = Data("Spain", "Ru, Es", "")
var data2 = Data("France", "Fr, En", "v1.0")
var data3 = Data("Germany", "", "v1.1")
```

and having an array of that object: `var list = mutableListOf(data1, data2, data3, data3)`

My idea is to order the list by these factors, ordered by importance, first factor is the most important, then, the others:

**Order factor 1:** `if (region == "Spain")` is the most important factor, anything with that condition must be before other regions. And if is not, then it should compare `if (region == "Europe")`. And if not, then should it compare `if (region == "World")`

**Order factor 2:** `if (language.contains("Es"))` is the second most important factor

**Order factor 3:** version. v1.1 is higher so must be in a more important position that v1.0. Numbers can be infinite, 1.1 and 1.0 are just samples. It must put higher versions before lower versions

How can this be implemented?

I tried this, with totally wrong results:

```
list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.region == "Spain"}, { it.language?.contains("Es") }, { it.version }))
```

Comment: `false < true`, so cases where `region` is not "Spain" will come first

Comment: @gpunto hi, I updated my question, please can you expand your explanation with some sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just provide 'numeric scores' for region/language/version -- exactly as you've described in your question. And because `compareBy` sorts elements in ascending order, lower numbers will be first.

```
val sorted = list.sortedWith(
    compareBy<Data>(
        {
            when (it.region.lowercase()) {
                "spain" -> 0
                "europe" -> 1
                "world" -> 2
                else -> 3
            }
        },
        {
            when {
                it.language.lowercase().contains("es") -> 0
                else -> 1
            }
        }
    ).thenByDescending {
        it.version
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi, it's interesting, I'm gonna test it later when I can. I see one problem with it.version. I used 1.1 and 1.0 as samples, but the numbers can be infinite, so, how can be that transformed into something that sorts putting higher versions before lower versions?

Comment: Well, you just have to come up with a way to transform the version-string to something comparable (maybe a double) -- see the edited answer

Comment: Hi there is an issue with the "version" comparing, because it crashes with "Double cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer"

Comment: maybe it's possible to compare lexicographically? I mean, v1.2 is greather than v1.1 lexycographically, and ver.b is greater than ver.a. Exists a way to compare them lexycographically instead of parsing to doubles? Whould be perfect as some items are versioned with letters instead that with numbers.

Comment: Well finally solved it simply returning "it.version" ! please edit your answer so I can accept it. Great job!